# gnome-tweak-tool 3.18 missing Window Theme option!

Tags: gnome, themes, window-manager, gnome-tweak-tool

I have installed Ubuntu Gnome 16.04.

But I saw something is wrong in `gnome-tweak-tool 3.18`

As you can see in below, the older version of `gnome-tweak-tool` had a Window Theme option :
[image]

But in `gnome-tweak-tool 3.18` there in no option for Window Theme :
[image]

And the question is how can I change Window Theme in `gnome-tweak-tool 3.18` ?

Any helps would be appreciated.

Comment: Gnome now does not allow separate GTK+ and Window themes. The GTK+ option will set both themes.

Answer (score 1):

Only way you can change window themes is by copying your theme to either Ambiance or Adwaita folder. Gnome developers have become very ignorant to user's and themes, due to their inability to fix underlying problems with their desktop. GTK+ will refuse to use the entire theme if it does not completely comply with what Gnome Developers want on our desktops. Remember, you have to use sudo nemo, nautilus and copy/paste theme to folder. Be prepared for Gnome 3.20 as does not support user themes at all!